# Retrieving my data from firebase 3

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I've been attempting to obtain my data from firebase 3 and was wondering if anybody knew of the error that I was making.

Service:

```
.service("searchService", function($firebaseArray, fb) {

    var database = firebase.database();
    var bookId = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    this.getPostedBooks = function() {
      return database.ref("postedBooks/" + bookId).once("value");
    }
```

Controller:

```
$scope.getPostedBooks = function() {
      searchService.getPostedBooks().then(function(response) {
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log(response.val())
        }, 5000);

        })
```

I attempted to use a timeout to see if the data was coming in late, but no matter what, I just get null.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the $q service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
.service("searchService", function($firebaseArray, $q, fb) {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var bookId = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var dfd = $q.defer();

    return {
       getPostedBooks :  function() {
      return database.ref("postedBooks/" + bookId).once("value", function(snapshot) {
          dfd.resolve(snapshot.val());
        }, function (errorObject) {
          //log error
        });
        return dfd.promise;
      }
    }
})
```